# reading MS word file in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, ms-word

I read MS word files by first converting it to zip and then getting its XML.

But it removes the newline characters and it is bothering me. what should I do?

I use this code:

```
function get_docx_content($filename) {
    //Check for extension
    $ext =  end(explode('.', $filename));

    //if its docx file
    if($ext == 'docx')
    $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    //else it must be odt file
    else
    $dataFile = "content.xml";

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This if it helps you.

```
    <?php



/*****************************************************************
This approach uses detection of NUL (chr(00)) and end line (chr(13))
to decide where the text is:
- divide the file contents up by chr(13)
- reject any slices containing a NUL
- stitch the rest together again
- clean up with a regular expression
*****************************************************************/

function parseWord($userDoc) 
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($userDoc, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($userDoc));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
} 

$userDoc = "cv.doc";

$text = parseWord($userDoc);
echo $text;


?>
```

If you want more for study it then look into

http://www.blogs.zeenor.com/it/read-ms-word-docx-ms-word-2007-file-document-using-php.html

Comment: no unfortunately it resulted in a mess of unknown characters more than hundreds while I had only 12 semantic words.